# A-Frame Video out of Multiple Shows Up as Black Screen only on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, ar.js

I'm trying to layer multiple transparent `.webm` videos using A-Frame's `<a-video>` to give a pop-out effect, yet some videos just don't load on mobile.

For example, I have three test videos that are suppose to automatically play:

- the back video is an mp4 on an `<a-plane>` as a `material`
- the middle is a `.webm` file I created in After Effects on an `<a-video>`
- the front video is also a `.webm` file I created in After Effects on an `<a-video>`

[IMG: On Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbtUv.jpg)

[IMG: On Pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHPyn.png)

For some reason the middle video never loads on mobile. I swapped it out with a .mp4 video and that worked fine. So I tried exporting the middle video as an .mp4, however the error still persisted!

I went through some github/stackoverflow and found posts talking about a similar issue (it's apparently been a long-running issue), but none of the fixes/workarounds really worked.

The resources I found:

- https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/faq.html#can-i-render-youtube-videos-as-a-texture
- https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/316#issuecomment-170182397
- https://www.reddit.com/r/WebVR/comments/40b3d2/using_aframe_video_works_on_pc_but_is_black_on/

And my code isn't doing anything fancy (HTML, just body):

```
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<a-scene embedded arjs="sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth:1280; sourceHeight:960; displayWidth: 1280; displayHeight: 960;">
    <a-assets>
        <video id="vid-1" loop="true" crossorigin="anonymous" 
               src='https://kucdinteractive.com/aomar/interactivespace/vid/LWA-ED.mp4'></video>
        <video id="vid-2" loop="true" crossorigin="anonymous" 
               src='https://kucdinteractive.com/aomar/interactivespace/vid/Test_Webv2.webm'></video>
        <video id="vid-pg4" autoplay loop="true" crossorigin="anonymous" 
               src='https://kucdinteractive.com/aomar/interactivespace/vid/Pg4-FULLSCENE(rq)_VP9.webm'></video>
    </a-assets>

    <a-marker preset='custom' type='pattern' url='https://kucdinteractive.com/aomar/interactivespace/img/pattern-veles.patt' vidhandler="target: #vid-1, #vid-2, #vid-pg4">
        <a-plane width="1.78" height="1"  rotation='270 0 0' src='#vid-1'></a-plane>
        <a-video width="1.32" height="1" rotation='270 0 0' position='0 0.5 0' src='#vid-pg4'></a-video>
        <a-video width="1.78" height="1" rotation='270 0 0' position='0 1 0' src='#vid-2'></a-video>
    </a-marker>

    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
</body>
```

(JS):

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('vidhandler', {
    schema: {
      target: {type: 'string'}
    },
    init: function() {
        this.videoNodes = document.querySelectorAll(this.data.target)
    },
    tick: function() {
        if (this.el.object3D.visible == true) {
            if (!this.toggle) {
                this.toggle = true;
                for (let i = 0; i < this.videoNodes.length; i++) {
                    this.videoNodes[i].play();
                } 
            }
        } else {
            if (this.toggle) {
              for (let i = 0; i < this.videoNodes.length; i++) {
                this.videoNodes[i].pause();
              }
              this.toggle = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Additional Info:

- Mobile: Samsung s20
- Mobile Browsers Tested: Samsung Internet, Chrome, Firefox (None
  worked)
- PC Browsers Tested: Chrome, Edge, Firefox (Worked)

Anyone have any workarounds on this bug?

Comment: [Works with other videos](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-69902933?path=index.html%3A6%3A0) (click for the three webms to play). My phone for sure hates the `5333 x 4033` video. Not sure about the others, the codec on the working ones is VP8, and yours have VP9. Did you try following the tips from the console logs (`OES_texture_float_linear` issues)?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski `Works with other videos example:` This example is really helpful, thank you!!! I'll try and recreate it with my video and see if the error persists. `Resolution:` Yea, I picked that resolution because it matched the ratio of the surface I planned to put the marker on. Though from your comment, that might be the part of the issue. `Logs:` I didn't see that error. If you are willing, could you send me a screenshot so I can look into it further? Thanks!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested what Piotr Adam Milewski commented and it was a resolution issue. When I scaled the video to fit a 1080p ratio, it worked on both devices! Also the [linked example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-69902933?path=index.html%3A6%3A0) he provided was really helpful at solving this!