# A-Frame v1.3.0 upon entering VR mode on mobile, screen goes black or grey

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm trying to try an A-Frame demo on my iPhone.
However, every time I press the VR mode button on one of the A-Frame examples and shift my device to the portrait orientation, the screen goes either black or grey depending on the scene setting.

The test setup I've tried is as follows:

- A-Frame v1.3.0
- iPhone 13 mini (iOS 15.6)
- Latest Safari, Google Chrome, and Firefox browsers

[A-Frame view before rotating the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsXHH.png)

[After the rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3sDN.png)

[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn6Gh.png)

[The line of code where it seems to produce the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeA4W.png)

I did look into other stackoverflow posts like below:
[A-Frame Video out of Multiple Shows Up as Black Screen only on Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902933/a-frame-video-out-of-multiple-shows-up-as-black-screen-only-on-mobile)
but all of them are either about video rendering or much older A-Frame versions.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could guide me on this.

Comment: Any console errors? This happens on video demos, or on the 'hello world' as well?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! The console outputs "TypeError: scope.dispatchEvent is not a function." (I've added the console screenshot to the post) when doing remote debugging on my iPhone but not on my laptop console.
And the issue doesn't happen on the video demo but on other A-Frame examples including "Hello World" and "Model Viewer" etc.